# D3-legend color always stays black

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been using this library [d3 legend](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/#color-threshold). Now I have set the scale and the color scale , I am getting the scale as expected but the color is black for the whole scale.[Screenshot of the legend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC1A0.png)

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8])
    .range(['#c6dbef','#a1c8e4','#7ab4da','#5692c5','#316aac','#08488a','#062c58','#03132b']);

var legend = d3.legendColor()
    .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
    .labels(d3.legendHelpers.thresholdLabels)
    .title("Color Legend")
    .useClass(true)
    .scale(color)
```

Comment: These are colored in the example [see](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/#color-threshold)

Comment: Link to the whole html - [link](https://codepad.co/snippet/ELwnmZ0g#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `useClass(true)`. According to the [documentation](http://d3-legend.susielu.com):

> If you set useClass to true then it will apply the scale's output as classes to the shapes instead of the fill or stroke.

Solution: just remove it:

```
var legend = d3.legendColor()
  .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
  .labels(d3.legendHelpers.thresholdLabels)
  .title("Color Legend")
  .scale(color)
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8]).range(['#c6dbef', '#a1c8e4', '#7ab4da', '#5692c5', '#316aac', '#08488a', '#062c58', '#03132b']);

var legend = d3.legendColor()
  .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
  .labels(d3.legendHelpers.thresholdLabels)
  .title("Color Legend")
  .scale(color)

svg.select(".legend")
  .call(legend);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.24.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue. It works perfectly.